# DbGeography POLYGON - increase dimensions by x kilometers

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, gis

So I have a polygon representing a rectangular bounding box covering a geographic wiht lat/lng coordinates using a kilometer based unit system.

The user wan't the application to find all matching objects within the bounding box + say 10 kilometers from outside any edge.  Finding objects within the box is fine, but **how do I expand it on all 4 sides by the specified number of kilometers?**

**Update**:

Used the solution below with the following observations:
A negative number is required to make the bounding box **expand**. The purple box is after the buffering.  The green box is the original bounding box. The red box is the original viewport.

I believe the results in SQL are also the wrong orientation since it finds results in London etc. Perhaps a bug in EF as I have to invert the lat and lng values to get Google maps to draw this polygon the right way up.

[image]

Comment: Given the comments in your update, you may have a ring orientation problem. That is, for a polygon with corners A, B, C, and D, POLYGON("A,B,C,D,A") isn't the same as POLYGON("A,D,C,B,A"). A simple heuristic is to check the area of the polygon with the STArea() method. If it returns an area larger than half the surface area of the planet, you've got the points defined backwards.

Comment: Thanks again @BenThul - I checked this (it seems different implementations work in either counter-clockwise or clockwise). I had only NE and SW coords, so I think I had the wrong combination - once I fixed that and switched to counter-clockwise (in SQL), then render in Google JavaScipt maps a poly clockwise - all is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [STBuffer method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933965.aspx). It would go something like this:

```
declare @g geography;
--set @g to your bounding box here
set @g = @g.STBuffer(10000);

select *
from dbo.yourTable
where @g.STContains( yourGeographyColumn );
```

Comment: Cheers, got me in the right direction. I updated my question with the results.